# How to Generate a Model in Anylogic on its own using the excel DB in personal learning edition? Could anyone please guide step by step?

Tags: anylogic

I have a Excel DB in .csv format, now I want to use that DB to generate a model in anylogic personal learning edition on its own.

I tried writing some java codes, but it didn't workout. Could anyone please help me step by step to solve this doubt?

Comment: Welcome to AnyLogic and SOF. First, help us help you: "I wrote some code but it didn't work" is not helpful :) . Second, check my workshop on the matter: it shows many of the required concepts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casVdmKC-S0&t=780s

Comment: oh, and start learning on how to make best use of the AnyLogic community, we are happy to help, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community